# Plot a letter image with geometry

Tags: wpf, xaml

I want an image which is a letter in a square. For example.

[image]

I want the background of the square is blue and the letter's letter is white.

The difficult thing is that I need many letters D and S etc. So I prefer a tool.

Comment: You want a custom Path ? Something like a SVG ? Or you want to use a Font with the letter D and S, and set Foreground and Background Brush / Color ?

Comment: @Tony, either one is okay. As long as I can reference it in the xaml, Actually I want  put the image in a button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this can help:

```
<WrapPanel TextBlock.FontFamily="Verdana">
    <Button Background="Blue">
        <Viewbox>
            <TextBlock Foreground="White">A</TextBlock>
        </Viewbox>
    </Button>
    <Button Background="Blue">
        <Viewbox>
            <TextBlock Foreground="White">B</TextBlock>
        </Viewbox>
    </Button>
    <Button Background="Blue">
        <Viewbox>
            <TextBlock Foreground="White">C</TextBlock>
        </Viewbox>
    </Button>
</WrapPanel>
```

[image: Sample]

Comment: I will use it in one place. However I do need a SVG into xaml in another place. Thanks

Comment: I will let this answer and add another answer with a SVG approach

Comment: Here is the SVG approach: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/50992744/194717